# how to change the status of the order to pending from complete?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, order-status

By mistake one of our order was marked as completed which not really completed. How shall we make the completed order again as pending?

Comment: I would suggest to credit memo this order and create a new one linked to Purchased order. This will keep the data integrity. No more missing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using code is **not easy to change order status** to **pending** from **Complete**.

By using some  mysql queries,you can do that but  it is your own rick.

First,you should **take backup of your database** then try **below queries**

**Query1:**

```
UPDATE `sales_flat_order` SET `status` = 'pending'
 WHERE `sales_flat_order`.`entity_id` = [Your_Order_id];
```

**Query2:**

```
UPDATE `sales_flat_order_grid` SET `status` = 'pending' 
WHERE `sales_flat_order_grid`.`entity_id` = [Your_Order_id];
```

As per as ,default magento,***an order can be complete*** when ***invoice and shipment are create for this order***

**So,you need to delete invoices & shipments for this order**

```
  $orderObject = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

     $invoiceCollection = $orderObject->getInvoiceCollection();
     foreach($invoiceCollection as $invoice):
        //var_dump($invoice);
        $invoiceId =  $invoice->getId();
        $invoiceObject = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($invoiceId);
        $invoiceObject->delete();
     endforeach;


     $invoiceCollection = $orderObject->getShipmentCollection();
     foreach($ShipmentCollection as $Shipment):
        //var_dump($Shipment);
        $ShipmentId =  $Shipment->getId();
        $ShipmentObject = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load($ShipmentId);
        $ShipmentObject->delete();
     endforeach;
```

Comment: When I tried to delete the invoiced and shipment section I am getting the error message as `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Cannot complete this operation from non-admin area.`